# Debugging an external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I'm using an external HDD which is my old laptop's HD with 2.5 SATA enclosure. I tried to delete a partition in Windows and stopped it unknowingly. When I reinsert it, my OS including Ubuntu freezes and sets some duplicate partition link in the launcher. Windows too failed the test.

Here's the screen of `disks` utility:
[image]

The drive is 320GB HD which is taken during the freeze. I unplugged it and plugged it and here the output screen of the command `dmesg`:

[image: dmesg output screen]

As you can see the value 6** keeps incrementing. I know that the drive is corrupted. But, how can I flash it. I already took a backup of everything in this drive. Is there any way to format fully and get the drive back? Can I use Windows to do that?

Comment: What good will flashing it do?

Comment: The point is I don't need any data. Can I reset the disk?